# Sending Array to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

How can I send data from one view controller to another via segue ?

```
country = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Afghanistan", @"Albania", 
@"Algeria", @"American Samoa", @"Andorra", @"Angola", @"Anguilla", @"Antarctica", 
@"Antigua and Barbuda", @"Argentina", @"Armenia", @"Aruba", @"Australia",
@"Austria", @"Azerbaijan", @"Bahamas", @"Bahrain", @"Bangladesh", @"Barbados",
@"Belarus", @"Belgium", @"Belize", @"Benin", @"Bermuda", @"Bhutan", @"Bolivia", 
@"Bosnia and Herzegovina", @"Botswana", @"Brazil", nil];


- (IBAction)onContactClick:(id)sender {

//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TableViewController" sender:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SMQuickSegue https://github.com/stefanomondino/SMQuickSegue it's really easy, follow the instruction and the example to include it via cocoapods (or just drag .h and .m file after downloading it), import the file in your view controller (extend SMQuickViewController if you can) and then

```
- (IBAction)onContactClick:(id)sender {
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TableViewController" parameters:@{@"country_array":country];
 }
```

where country is your array and country_array is a property in your "next" view controller.